# Removing everything in a string before a specific phrase and after a specific phrase

Tags: c#, string

I have a string and I want to delete everything before a phrase, and then delete everything after a different phrase.  i.e.,

```
myString = "words words words FIRSTPHRASE these words I want SECONDPHRASE but not these words"
```

So the new string would be `"these words I want"`.

Comment: Yup I slipped and hit enter :P  fixed now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  `String.Substring` and [`String.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it has also an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33.aspx) with a start index:

```
string myString = "words words words FIRSTPHRASE these words I want SECONDPHRASE but not these words";
string result = myString;
int indexOfFirstPhrase = myString.IndexOf("FIRSTPHRASE");
if(indexOfFirstPhrase >= 0)
{
    indexOfFirstPhrase += "FIRSTPHRASE".Length;
    int indexOfSecondPhrase = myString.IndexOf("SECONDPHRASE", indexOfFirstPhrase);
    if (indexOfSecondPhrase >= 0)
        result = myString.Substring(indexOfFirstPhrase, indexOfSecondPhrase - indexOfFirstPhrase);
    else
        result = myString.Substring(indexOfFirstPhrase);
}
```

<kbd>[**Demonstration**](http://ideone.com/1VEoQo)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
string theWordsIWant = Regex.Replace(myString, @"^.*?FIRSTPHRASE\s*(.*?)\s*SECONDPHRASE.*$", "$1");
```

<kbd>[**Demonstration**](http://ideone.com/j47CjL)</kbd>